pip and system python (3.12.4) don't work properly anymore after installing pyenv
I installed pyenv to run an old code on python 3.7.17. Now I need to go back to version 3.12.4 which is the system python (before installing pyenv). But right now I can't even run pip :/
➜  ~ pip install <CLI-package-name>
pyenv: pip: command not found

The `pip' command exists in these Python versions:
  3.7.17
  3.7.17/envs/glue_3.7.17
  glue_3.7.17

Note: See 'pyenv help global' for tips on allowing both
      python2 and python3 to be found.

➜ ~ which pip
/Users/fmdnst/.pyenv/shims/pip

Same thing for running python:
➜  ~ python
pyenv: python: command not found

The `python' command exists in these Python versions:
  3.7.17
  3.7.17/envs/glue_3.7.17
  glue_3.7.17

Note: See 'pyenv help global' for tips on allowing both
      python2 and python3 to be found.
➜  ~ which python
/Users/fmdnst/.pyenv/shims/python

Here is the output of pyenv versions, so I am on the correct python version (I guess):
➜  ~ pyenv versions
* system (set by /Users/fmdnst/.pyenv/version)
  3.7.17
  3.7.17/envs/glue_3.7.17
  glue_3.7.17 --> /Users/fmdnst/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/envs/glue_3.7.17

I also tried to install the package as follow but it didn't work:
➜  ~ pip3.12 install <CLI-package-name>
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try brew install
    xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.

If you wish to install a Python library that isn't in Homebrew,
use a virtual environment:

python3 -m venv path/to/venv
source path/to/venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install xyz

If you wish to install a Python application that isn't in Homebrew,
it may be easiest to use 'pipx install xyz', which will manage a
virtual environment for you. You can install pipx with

brew install pipx

You may restore the old behavior of pip by passing
the '--break-system-packages' flag to pip, or by adding
'break-system-packages = true' to your pip.conf file. The latter
will permanently disable this error.

If you disable this error, we STRONGLY recommend that you additionally
pass the '--user' flag to pip, or set 'user = true' in your pip.conf
file. Failure to do this can result in a broken Homebrew installation.

Read more about this behavior here: <https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/>

So following that instructions, I ran the following command:
➜  ~ python3.12 -m pip install --break-system-packages <CLI-package-name>

And this worked and said the package is installed successfully, but I can't find it anywhere and it's not available in bash. I'm quite lost and don't know what's happening. Could someone please help me to understand how to install a package as before?!
If I try to run python from bash, I can see the following options are available:
➜  ~ python
python             python-config      python3-config     python3.12-config  python3.7-config   python3.7m
python-build       python3            python3.12         python3.7          python3.7-gdb.py   python3.7m-config

And if I run python3.12 it gives me the correct python shell, but running python command says that pyenv: python: command not found
Also, I added the following to my zshrc:
➜  ~ echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.zshrc
➜  ~ echo '[[ -d $PYENV_ROOT/bin ]] && export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
➜  ~ echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc


orient yourself: which python/which pip/which pip3 etc -> shows you which python/pip is used. When having multiple system-pythons installed and want to use pip, you should always make sure that you use the according python version, otherwise you may install pkgs for the wrong version. you can always make sure that you install it for the correct version using python3.xx -m pip install(/list) <pkg-name> and regarding your question: sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.12 1 and sudo update-alternatives --config python to set the version.

it seems that you don't have python 3.12.4 installed. 'pyenv versions' lists the python versions installed in the pyenv directory. i see only 3.7.17 installed. you'll have to install the version you want in the directory.
there is a new version of python (3.12.5) btw. you can install that version: pyenv install 3.12.5, and then make it global to select it as your preferred version: pyenv global 3.12.5. i would update pyenv first using brew, which auto-updates before starting any update process. use this script: brew upgrade pyenv.
reminder: install first the build dependencies for python before installing python itself. see https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment for guide.
you can try this to install packages: pyenv exec pip3 install package_name. 'pyenv exec' is equivalent to, for example, PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/versions/3.9.7/bin:$PATH", which is path to bin of currently selected python version
refer to https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md for commands, or installation guide at https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/tree/master

By the looks of it, OP wants to use their system-provided Python 3.12, not a pyenv-provided one. The issue is their pip command is replaced by a pyenv shim.

Your answer should focus more on the question. There is off-topic, like python3.12.5, etc. You could point out how the OS works and give advice for information that you need to answer the question detailed and give a step by step explanation. You need to catch people where they are.
