What to use instead of distutils in setup.py python3.12
I'm trying to create a setup.py file and found that distutils has been deprecated.  Is there something else setup.py or distutils has been replaced by which I am meant to use instead or should I try using setuptools.dist?

See the Whats New Section. Remove the distutils package. See the migration guide for advice replacing the APIs it provided. The third-party Setuptools package continues to provide distutils, if you still require it in Python 3.12 and beyond

You can use setup to achieve this, here is a similar setuptoopls.py file you can use

setup() Function: The central function provided by setuptools to handle the packaging,

while the find_packages(): Automatically finds all packages and subpackage.

Metadata: Includes name, version, author, author_email, description, etc.
4 .Classifiers: Used to provide metadata about your package (e.g., supported Python versions, license).

install_requires: Lists dependencies that need to be installed alongside your package.
 from setuptools import setup, find_packages

 setup(
     name="your_package_name",
     version="0.1.0",
     author="Your Name",
     author_email="your_email@example.com",
     description="A brief description of your package",
     long_description=open("README.md").read(),
     long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
     url="https://github.com/yourusername/your-repo",
     packages=find_packages(),
     classifiers=[
         "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
         "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
         "Operating System :: OS Independent",
     ],
     python_requires='>=3.6',
     install_requires=[
         # List your package dependencies here, e.g.
         # "numpy >= 1.18.0",
     ],

)



python3 -m pip install -e . does not seem to install it for me. (when I then try to run import "your_package_name" I get a ModuleNotFoundError)

hi Kolayan1, I think I am aware of the error what you need to do is cd/root dir of your project , then run your command, and other thing could be the way you are importing your_package_name  you might want to do something like this from src import your_package_name where you want to use "your_package_name" do this and let us see what happens

Hi D.Iola thanks for the response. Actually, the problem is that setup.py installations don't work for python 3.12 anymore. So one needs to change to pyproject.toml. Such as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78822863/pip-and-system-python-3-12-4-dont-work-properly-anymore-after-installing-pyen or https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html

you are welcome :) hmm but a quick search says they still maintain it see ref: docs click on setup.py. Plus your error doesn't point to unsupported setup config. The error seems to be related to not running the command in the root directory especially, if "your_package" doesn't have a dunder method __main__ , python wouldn't be able to find it or if you don't have an __init__.py file. in your package folder. Did you have a look at the folder structure provided in the link you sent? cd/project_root_directory

Here is my ref https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/setup-py-deprecated/

Hmm. I need to investigate this further. What solved it for me is adding a pyproject.toml. Perhaps, pyproject can still work with setup.py, but it seems a pyproject.toml file is needed in any case.

yeah, I guess you might have too but I am sure it does work for 3.12 at least.

distutils is replaced fully by setuptools. setuptools.setup is equivalent of distutils.core.setup and setuptools.Extension is equivalent of distutils.core.Extension.

but what version of setuptools replaced it and is compatible with python3.12.  I am getting errors because my version still calls the disutils.core and distutil.filelist.    File "/workspace/mktplace/env/lib64/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/init.py", line 9, in 
import distutils.core
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
